# Xcode 'Hide status bar' pushes content upward

Tags: ios, xcode

When I set my app to "Hide status bar" in Xcode, the content appears pushed upward a bit on all devices except iPhone 11 (on the simulator). With "Hide status bar" disabled, the content is positioned correctly.

Does anyone know how to hide the status bar without affecting the layout? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. Your content is pinned to the safe area. The safe area top moves up if the status bar goes away on a device with a bezel.

Comment: It’s not a problem. It’s normal. If you don’t like it, don’t pin to the safe area or don’t change the status bar visibility before the user’s eyes.